# TFS endpoint services to external web service

Tags: tfs, endpoint

I'm using TFS 2015 Update 3 with no internet access.

I'm trying to create a service endpoint for an external web service on the internet. I can add the url with auth but of course it will not work. Can I use endpoint with a proxy (I have a proxy server in my org)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The proxy of course should be work, the problem for TFS server is no internet access. So you just need to configure the TFS server to access internet via the proxy server.

Reference this article : [TFS 2015 behind a proxy](http://blog.majcica.com/2016/03/08/tfs-2015-behind-a-proxy/)